# Rhetorical structure theory (RST) package

Tags: parsing, nlp, semantics

I work in a project where I need a package for rhetorical structure theory. I have found some packages but I need one that allows the access to its resources through a programing language (http://www.sfu.ca/rst/) and (http://www.wagsoft.com/RSTTool/section2.html).

Thanks for the help.

Comment: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:Alvations/nlp_tools

Comment: I have found : https://github.com/planet42/Laika/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/laika/parse/rst/ReStructuredText.scala